# How to show all books not associated with a user. many-to-many relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have 3 tables in my database. users, books and book_user.
book_user is the pivot table that manages the many-to-many relationship between users and books.

I have the Laravel relationship correctly setup and i am able to display all the books associated to a user using the following in Laravel.

```
   $user = Auth::user();
  return response()->json($user->books()->get());
```

Now i am trying to display all the books that are NOT associated to a particular user. I have been struggling for quite some time and cant seem to find anything that works. Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the book is not related to the user then you should not try to retrieve it via the user. Instead use the book model:

```
Book::whereDoesntHave('users', function ($q) {
      $q->where('id', \Auth::id());
})->get();
```

Comment: Dude i honestly love you. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you want all books not belonging to any user at all, instead of all books not belonging to a particular user, you could do something like :

```
$books = Book::whereDoesntExists(function($query) {
    $query->select('book_user.id_book')
          ->from('book_user')
          ->where('book_user.id_book', '=', 'books.id');
    // Assuming that the columns on the pivot table are 'id_book' and 'id_user' and the primary key is 'id' in the 'books' table.
});
```

Here you fetch all books that haven't their id in the book_user pivot table's id_book column. So basically, all books not belonging to any user.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. I am trying to display all books not belonging to a particular user. You are correct in assumptions regarding the table names though :) Kind regards, Matt.